# Smartly handle different permissions with inheritance

Tags: python, permissions, getattr

I have to manage permissions and I have different user types, as for
example a couple here.

```
def not_allowed(*args, **kwargs): return False

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return not_allowed

    def view_profile(self)
        return True


class Admin(User):
    def edit_comment(self):
        return True

class Expert(User):
    def delete_post(self):
        return True


user = {'userid': 'user', 'roles': ['admin', 'expert']}
```

Now I want to be able to have MultiRole type, which in theory should
simply be able to do everything that its roles are able to do.

I tried with something like this:

```
class MultiRoleUser(User):
    """A multirole user has all the power of all the roles together
    """
    def __init__(self, userid, roles):
        super(MultiRoleUser, self).__init__(userid)
        self.roles = roles

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        all_funcs = [getattr(x, attr) for x in self.roles]
        return any(x() for x in all_funcs)
```

Which should be used as

```
u = MultiRoleUser('userid', [Admin, Expert])
```

But it doesn't work, ideally I would like to call the methods for all
the classes passed in and do a or (with any).

The problem is that to call the methods I need to have an object of
that type..

In theory I might even just use a dictionary for each role instead,
but I liked the default to false trick which makes, and sometimes I
also need a function to compute the permission.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For starters, why are you rolling your own authorization framework? This is a solved problem, and both uniform enough and hard enough to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Because at the moment I have no choice, but I'm open to suggestions for further integrations (the API is running on bottle). Anyway it's really simple when I get this last thing it's done I will be good with 60 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I tend to agree that you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel on this, below is version of your attempt that appears to work AFAIK.

Basically, I first I had switch to explicit new-style classes by making them derived from `object` so that the `super()` call would work, then second, I changed the `self.roles = roles` initialization in the `MultiRoleUser` class to create the instances needed. Lastly I changed how the `MultiRoleUser.__getattr__()`used them to handle role classes that didn't have the sought permission attribute.

```
def not_allowed(*args, **kwargs): return False

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return not_allowed

    def view_profile(self):
        return True

class Admin(User):
    def edit_comment(self):
        return True

class Expert(User):
    def delete_post(self):
        return True

class MultiRoleUser(User):
    """A multirole user has all the power of all the roles together"""
    def __init__(self, userid, roles):
        super(MultiRoleUser, self).__init__(userid)
        self.roles = [role(userid) for role in roles] # create instances needed

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        all_funcs = [getattr(x, attr, None) for x in self.roles]
        return any(x() for x in all_funcs if x) # check permission if there was one

u = MultiRoleUser('userid', [Admin, Expert])

print 'u.edit_comment:', u.edit_comment
print 'u.delete_post:', u.delete_post
```

BTW, I think a better Python implementation would use `sets` and operations with them to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok there were a couple of mistakes in the code: 1. in the real code I was using new style classes already. 2. I need the inheritance in Admin an Expert which implies that 3. role() would not work because I need to pass the "userid".
Thanks!

Comment: Fine, I've added those things from the revised code in your question to my answer -- which doesn't change the fact my other suggestions for changes make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer which uses multiple inheritance and properties to **greatly** simplify the implementation (because, once again, you were essentially reinventing wheels). It completely eliminates the need to have a `roles` attribute in the `MultiRoleUser` class, as well as the specialized `getattr()` method required to make use it.

The idea for using multiple inheritance occurred to me because it seemed odd to define `class MultiRoleUser` as *having* multiple instances of `User` sublclasses, rather than just *being* one itself. The idea of using properties came as a result of thinking about the fact that the `gettattr()` the class required by the class was *calling* the function attributes found to get their values, which is part of what properties are all about.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, userid):
        self.userid = userid

    def __getattr__(self, attr):  # unknown/undefined permission
        return False

    @property
    def view_profile(self):
        return True

class Admin(User):
    @property
    def edit_comment(self):
        return True

class Expert(User):
    @property
    def delete_post(self):
        return True

def multi_role_user(cls_name, *roles):
    """Factory function to create a multirole user class which has the combined
       power of all the User subclasses given"""
    if not roles:
        raise TypeError('at least one subclass of class User must be specified')
    if not all(issubclass(role, User) for role in roles):
        raise TypeError('all roles must be subclasses of class User')
    return type(cls_name, roles, {})

MultiRoleUser = multi_role_user('MultiRoleUser', Admin, Expert)
u = MultiRoleUser('my_userid')

print 'u.userid:', u.userid
print 'u.view_profile:', u.view_profile
print 'u.edit_comment:', u.edit_comment
print 'u.delete_post:', u.delete_post
print 'u.can_spam:', u.can_spam
```

Comment: That's nice, but I don't want to create a class for each possible combination of different roles, so I should generate the classes dynamically, which I'm not sure is much better..

Comment: Oh, it's still possible to dynamically generate different subclasses if desired, which I've updated the answer to illustrate how to do. Most of the added factory function is error checking.